# Can I stop Aptana's PDT plugin from messing with my Javascript editing

Tags: php, javascript, ide, aptana

I run Aptana 2.0 on Win 7. I normally code HMTL/CSS/JS but the other day I started with a PHP project, so I downloaded the PDT plugin to get proper colorization in .PHP files.

It works fine, but my problem is that PDT also seems to mess with Javascript editing (applies another colorization scheme that's the same as in PHP files, and code completion doesn't work anymore).

Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a fix? Or is there another PHP plugin out there (all I want is proper colorization of the HTML in PHP files...)?

Any tip is appreciated, thanks!

/Joolss

Comment: Aptana 2.0 is a horrible IDE, Aptana 1.5 was really better. I really hope 2.1 will implement all the good features 1.5 had, and I'm not the only one to be disapointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually edit colors for syntax highlighting on a per plugin basis from the settings panel in Aptana. Also, syntax coloring depends on the editor you used to open the file with. Try right clicking the file you want to open and pick 'open with editor' and dont pick the php one.

Comment: Excellent, thanx! rightclick -> "Open width..." -> "Aptana JS Editor" did the trick, at least per file basis.

Comment: To set the default JS editor, i clicked "Preferences" -> "General" -> "Editors" -> "File Associations", picked "*.js", selected the editor I wanted and clicked "Default"